# how to coordinate file sharing between .net backend and asp.net web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My system .NET windows app backend reads and writes files.

Its corresponding asp.net web app sometimes reads from these files.

Sometimes, web reads incorrect data from files because backend is writing at same time.

For example, backend needs to update two files, so ..
1. backend updates the 1st file,
2. meanwhile web reads the 2nd file,
3. then backend updates 2nd file,
4. then web reads 1st file,
...so now web has corrupt data: its copy of 2nd file is out-of-date.

How can I prevent this?

File system is just Windows file system text files, not SQL.

Comment: you mean file 1 and file 2 belong together like a transaction? you could either force lock files while reading or better write to file_1.tmp and file_2.tmp and when completely ready. replace/delete with the old files. this way the ASP site does not need to be aware of the change?

Comment: based on what you have explained, whenever the backend is updating the data all the reads before this update had fetched the wrong data, not just that one which is at the same time of the update. But if you mean all those reads are wrong which are close to the update action then you can solve this by lots of approaches. you can have a shared memory, a cache for example that keeps the state or lock,  both apps need to have access to that one. OR you can have a service which is reading and updating data and both of your apps can ask the service to do the update and reads.